Chromium: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
Whenever running the following command for bigger html files (resulting in multiple pages):
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox -enable-logging=stderr --v=2 --print-to-pdf=output.pdf input.html

I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')\n    at printToPDF (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:243:26)\n    at async handleCommands (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:262:31)\n    at async executeCommands (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:334:18)

Below is the full log file without histograms:
[0902/084559.463892:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 12
[0902/084559.463892:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 12
[0902/084559.466314:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(201)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[0902/084559.466313:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(201)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[0902/084559.468694:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0902/084559.493015:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0902/084559.493041:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0902/084559.496144:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(123)] Could not get the download directory.
[0902/084559.496291:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(1410)] MSM::InitializeMaybeAsync([this=0x24001c9600])
[0902/084559.496637:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(1410)] MDM::MediaDevicesManager()
[0902/084559.496665:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(1410)] MSM::MediaStreamManager([this=0x24001c9600]))
[0902/084559.497254:VERBOSE2:policy_service_impl.cc(515)] Policy refresh complete
[0902/084559.498580:VERBOSE1:key_storage_util_linux.cc(52)] Password storage detected desktop environment: (unknown)
[0902/084559.498628:VERBOSE1:key_storage_linux.cc(118)] Selected backend for OSCrypt: BASIC_TEXT
[0902/084559.498658:VERBOSE1:key_storage_linux.cc(137)] OSCrypt did not initialize a backend.
[0902/084559.502080:VERBOSE1:va_stubs.cc(666)] dlopen(libva.so.2) failed.
[0902/084559.502199:VERBOSE1:va_stubs.cc(668)] dlerror() says:
libva.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0902/084559.502255:VERBOSE1:vaapi_wrapper.cc(1573)] GetHandle(): Either VADisplayStateSingleton::PreSandboxInitialization() hasn't been called or that method failed to find a suitable render node
[0902/084559.511444:VERBOSE1:first_party_sets_handler_impl_instance.cc(276)] Empty path. Failed initializing First-Party Sets database.
[0902/084559.511946:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0902/084559.525786:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(803)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0902/084559.526465:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(803)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0902/084559.574658:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(177)] 
[CDP SEND] {
   "id": 0,
   "method": "Target.exposeDevToolsProtocol",
   "params": {
      "targetId": "5565682A48638CB3F5E5CACD5862E6F0"
   }
}

[0902/084559.574893:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(177)] 
[CDP SEND] {
   "id": 1,
   "method": "Inspector.enable"
}

[0902/084559.574922:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(177)] 
[CDP SEND] {
   "id": 2,
   "method": "Runtime.evaluate",
   "params": {
      "awaitPromise": true,
      "expression": "executeCommands(JSON.parse('{\"printToPDF\":{},\"targetUrl\":\"file:///report-writer/storage/report_run_20240902065553_704.html\"}'))",
      "returnByValue": true
   }
}

[0902/084559.575028:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(126)] 
[CDP RECV] {
   "id": 0,
   "result": {
   }
}

[0902/084559.575039:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(126)] 
[CDP RECV] {
   "id": 1,
   "result": {
   }
}

[0902/084559.580021:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(803)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0902/084559.596358:VERBOSE1:file_url_loader_factory.cc(453)] FileURLLoader::Start: file:///report-writer/storage/report_run_20240902065553_704.html
[0902/084559.617948:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://localhost:8000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBZ2cvIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--af2b60602a7f1891abd29a5483e730f5c3f97f8a/GAPAssocImage.jpg
[0902/084559.621595:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(35)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://hcp2020-stage.s3.amazonaws.com/USGA_Logo_Scaled.jpg
[0902/084619.634332:VERBOSE2:simple_devtools_protocol_client.cc(126)] 
[CDP RECV] {
   "id": 2,
   "result": {
      "exceptionDetails": {
         "columnNumber": 26,
         "exception": {
            "className": "TypeError",
            "description": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')\n    at printToPDF (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:243:26)\n    at async handleCommands (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:262:31)\n    at async executeCommands (chrome://headless/headless_command.js:334:18)",
            "objectId": "-6008844575594007179.1.1",
            "subtype": "error",
            "type": "object"
         },
         "exceptionId": 1,
         "lineNumber": 243,
         "scriptId": "3",
         "stackTrace": {
            "callFrames": [ {
               "columnNumber": 25,
               "functionName": "printToPDF",
               "lineNumber": 242,
               "scriptId": "3",
               "url": "chrome://headless/headless_command.js"
            } ]
         },
         "text": "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"
      },
      "result": {
         "type": "object",
         "value": {
         }
      }
   }
}

Do you know why this is happening and how to fix it?
Environment: docker container with debian-bullseye-slim and chromium 120.0.6099.224-1~deb11u1
